# $(eval ) in makefile causing recipe commences before first target error

Tags: makefile, eval

```
CFormat:

define Format_File :=
    @echo Formatting
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(1))","")
    @echo if1

    # The default extensions for intermediate files are not used,
    # to avoid collisions with backup files open in the editor, etc.
    # Save the original source file with an '_X' suffix on the extension.
ifneq("$(wildcard $(1)_X)","") 
    @echo if2
else 
    @echo else2
endif
    @ren $(1) $(1)_X
    # C-Comment is invoked separately, due to pathing limitations
    # The redirection is a means to suppress blabbering.
    @echo Formatting $(1) . . .
    $(CFORMAT_PATH)\Cformat -h$(CFORMAT_PATH) $(1)_X -o$[Base, $(1)].tmp -ino >temp.tmp; 
    $(CFORMAT_PATH)\Ccomment -h$(CFORMAT_PATH) $[Base, $(1)].tmp -o$(1) >temp.tmp; 
else 
    @echo else1
endif
endef


FormatAll: CFormat
$(foreach loopFile,$(ALL_S_SOURCES),$(eval $(call Format_File,$(loopFile))))


.PHONY: FormatAll
```

When I replaced eval with info it printed out the function call correctly but every time I try to actually eval the formatter it gives me the error in the title.

Edit: This question was plagued with syntax errors everywhere but following the advice of @MadScientist I was eventually able to get it to work using shell loops.

Comment: What is `ALL_S_SOURCES`? What else is in that makefile? What version of make? With that exact snippet I don't that error with a few different versions of make. (As an aside what is `$[Base, $(1)].tmp` supposed to be doing in that recipe line for you?)

Comment: And actually if I fill in `ALL_S_SOURCES` with a filename (that exists) I get a missing separator error. That define looks like it wants to output recipe lines but `$(eval)` doesn't generate any output. Also assigning a define with `:=` causes it to be evaluated **immediately** which means all your `$1` references are going to be empty. In short this isn't even close to being able to work as-is.

Comment: Even if I replace the entire define with one echo statement I still cant get it to echo once for every file in the list.

Comment: To get it to echo at recipe execution time you need to remove `$(eval)` from the `foreach` loop. Change the define to be `echo $(1)`. Put `@` before the `$(foreach)` and indent it with a tab. Then put `;` at the end of the last argument of the `$(foreach)` call. Roughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest answer is, you can't do it that way.  A single function like `$(foreach ...)`, or a single variable expansion, can *never* expand to multiple logical lines in a makefile.  That's just not how the make parser works.

Further, `$(eval ...)`  can be used to construct a complete rule but you can't use it to build just part of a rule: before make starts to parse the output of the evaluation it will "close" any rule that's currently being defined (just like you can't put the introduction of a rule in one file and the recipe in another file and use `include` to include the recipe).

You haven't really explained why you want to do things in just this way.  One simple answer is to use shell loops, not makefile loops, like this:

```
FormatAll: CFormat
        @for f in $(ALL_S_SOURCES); do \
            echo Formatting; \
            if [ -f $$f ]; then \
                echo if1; \
                if [ -f $${f}_X ]; then \ 
                    echo if2; \
                else \
                    echo else2; \
                fi; \
                ren $$f $${f}_X; \
                echo Formatting $$f . . .; \
                $(CFORMAT_PATH)\Cformat -h$(CFORMAT_PATH) $F{f}_X -o$[Base, $$f].tmp -ino >temp.tmp; \
                $(CFORMAT_PATH)\Ccomment -h$(CFORMAT_PATH) $[Base, $$f].tmp -o$$f >temp.tmp; \
            else \
                echo else1; \
            fi; \
        done
```

I agree with Etan that the `$[Base ...]` syntax is weird and certainly isn't right.

If you want more details about `eval` and debugging, you might check out [this post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/the-eval-function/) and the earlier ones in the series.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: the `foreach` loop spits out recipe commands before/outside of a target recipe definition.

You can try something like:

```
all: 
    $(foreach loopFile,$(ALL_S_SOURCES),$(eval $(call Format_File,$(loopFile))))

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error with the added at the bottom, I've adjusted the code above to reflect the change.