# Makefile function from make commands, NOT shell commands

Tags: makefile

Is there any way to create multiline functions out of Makefile commands?

I know we can do something like this to encapsulate a recipe (of shell commands) as a function:

```
define function
    @echo 'First argument: $1'
    @echo 'Second argument: $2'
endef

.PHONY test-function
test-function:
    $(call function, a, b)
```

With this, running `make test-function` will give the output:

```
First argument: a
Second argument: b
```

I also know we can use the `call` directive with one-line macros consisting of make syntax/directives (example taken from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function)):

```
pathsearch = $(firstword $(wildcard $(addsuffix /$(1),$(subst :, ,$(PATH)))))

LS := $(call pathsearch,ls)
```

But let's say I wanted to `call` a macro made up of multiple make commands, including conditionals. How would I achieve that?

When I run `make build-type=API build` with the following Makefile:

```
define check-arguments
ifeq ($1, api)
     @echo 'Building API'
else ifeq ($1, service)
     @echo 'Building Service'
else
     $$(error 'Build type must be API or Service')
endif
endef

.PHONY: build
build:
$(call check-arguments, $(build-type))
    @echo 'Starting build'
    ...
    ...
```

I keep getting the error `Makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop.`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html). The GNU Make Manual states:

> ...it [`eval`] allows you to define new makefile constructs that are not constant; which are the result of evaluating other variables and functions.

`eval` will parse `ifeq` and `$(error)` as part of the makefile instead of as commands for the recipe.

One thing to keep in mind is that `eval` parses its input by itself, without regard for the surrounding syntax of the makefile. This means that you cannot use it to define only part of a rule, like in your example:

```
build:
$(call check-arguments, $(build-type))
```

If we use `$(eval $(call check-arguments, $(build-type)))`, then `eval` will parse the expansion of `check-arguments` by itself and complain because the recipe has no target. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29926063/10850779).) The solution here is to include `build:` in `check-arguments` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

While having `$(eval)` is fine, I would like to recommend a different approach, based on target resolution instead of conditionals, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
supported_build_types := api service

.PHONY: build
build: build-$(build-type)

.PHONY: $(addprefix build-,$(supported_build_types))
$(addprefix build-,$(supported_build_types)): build-%:
        @echo 'Building $*'
        @echo 'Starting build'

.PHONY: build-
build-:
        $(error Must provide build-type of: $(supported_build_types))

.PHONY: build-%
build-%:
        $(error Unsupported build type: $*. Must be one of: $(supported_build_types))
```

This can allow easier extensibility and maintenance while keeping away nuisances of `$(eval)`s, `$(call)`s and appropriate escaping.

Running supported build types:

```
$ make build build-type=api
Building api
Starting build

$ make build build-type=service
Building service
Starting build
```

Invalid build type:

```
$ make build build-type=foo
Makefile:17: *** Unsupported build type: foo. Must be one of: api service.  Stop.
```

Missing build type:

```
$ make build
Makefile:13: *** Must provide build-type of: api service.  Stop.
```

Comment: On line 7 of the sample Makefile, what does the colon after `build-%` signify? It throws my understanding of make out of whack. I thought `build-%` was the prerequisite (as it showed up after the colon)...but `build-%` also has a colon after it...so now what?

Comment: It's called a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html). Apparently it lets the pattern rule apply only to a select set of targets. (That's also why the `build-%:` rule at the very end works as a fallback.)